# C++ (g++ compiler) Dynamically Initializing Statically Declared Array Leads to Memory Questions

Tags: c++, g++

We went over differing compiler behavior today in my data structures class. The example below (plus some of my cout'ing and other tinkering) was given as a program that could compile on g++ but not necessarily on all other compilers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int j = 5;

    cout << "i address: " << &i << " -- j address: " << &j 
         << endl << "enter size: ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "value i: "<< i << "; size memory of i (ints): "<<(&i - &j)<< endl;

    int a[i];

    cout << "address of array a start: " << a << endl;

    int b = 14;

    cout << "value b: " << b << "; b address= " << &b << endl
         << "distance bt j and b(ints): "<< (&j - &b) << endl;
    cout << "distance bt b and start of array(ints): " << (&b - a) << endl;
}
```

After playing around with inputs (and learning a little about how dynamic arrays are allocated memory in the process), I decided that entering 0 was the most interesting. The output:

```
i address: 0x7fff5b303764 -- j address: 0x7fff5b303760
enter size: 0
value i: 0; size memory of i (ints): 1
address of array a start: 0x7fff5b3036b0
value b: 14; b address= 0x7fff5b303754
distance bt j and b(ints): 3
distance bt b and start of array(ints): 41
```

## My Questions:

1. How does g++ know to treat the array a as one which needs to be dynamically created vs    immediately trying to statically create one with whatever the default value of i is or throwing some sort of compile time error?
2. The distance between j and b is 3 ints worth of memory instead of the expected 1. What is going on with that? I suspect, purely from empirical evidence gathered by playing around with the program, that it has something to do with the couts, but I'm unfamiliar with how/why they would be stored in memory in seemingly random amounts.
3. I entered 0 for size of array a and, based on playing around with different sizes, I think it is unlikely that a dynamic array of length 0 would be initialized to length 41. So, if it is not the array taking up all of those 41 ints worth of memory, what then is stored between b (the last data stored on the stack) and the array a (the first data purposefully stored on the heap) and why is whatever it is there?

Comment: All of these pointer subtractions cause undefined behaviour.  It might be instructive to examine the assembly code produced by this program, in order to understand what g++ is doing.

Comment: [Link to unoptimized assembly](http://goo.gl/in9nEY)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have never worked with assembly language before. But it's great to know that I can use it as a resource to more deeply examine exactly what is going on in these situations in the future. Will definitely take a look back at the link you provided when I feel comfortable enough with the topic to do so as there are still some ambiguities as to just what exactly is going on here. I appreciate your time and effort in responding to my questions. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a variable-length array which is not part of standard C++ but a g++ extension. g++ knows that it is not a regular array with size determined at compile-time, because `i` is not a compile-time constant, such as `const int i = 3;` `a` is not stored on the heap. It is stored on the stack. I imagine the address distance between `j` and `b` depends on the size allocated to `a`, which can only be known at run-time. I don't know how to account for the distance between `b` and `a` for size 0. If you built in debug-mode, it's possible that some extra hidden buffer was added after the array in order to detect an accidental overwrite beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: According to what you said, the memory allocated to a is on the stack and also allocated at runtime? How is it not in between j and b in this case? Their relative positions in memory go like this (distances in ints) i -1-> j -3-> b -41-> a. How can the distance between j and b be accounted for by a if a is after b not in between them? Does it get moved at some point?

Comment: @jvanstry I did not look too closely at the precise numbers. The compiler is able to reorder these variables on the stack if it wants to. Also sometimes for `x - y`, you put the variable later first and sometimes the variable earlier first. I don't know how that will affect the calculation.

Comment: The compiler can arrange variables on the stack however it wants.  Most likely, it puts all the variable-length stuff above all the fixed-size stuff so that all the fixed-size variables are at constant positions that don't depend on the size of the array.

Comment: @Wyzard when you say above, do you mean at a lower # memory address?

Comment: It seems like I'm getting contradictory answers here: @Wyzard stated the dynamic elements are stored above the static ones, and Neil Kirk mentioned that the 3 int spacing bt j and b is based on a, implying its between these elements. Could someone clear up this apparent discrepancy?

Comment: On typical operating systems on x86, yes, actually, because the stack "grows" downward in memory.  But that's platform-specific; in general you can't really rely on one variable being at a higher or lower address than another.  The point is that it makes sense to group fixed-size variables together instead of having variable-length arrays between them.

Comment: @jvanstry I said "imagine", which I meant to mean I'm not sure :) Curiosity and tinkering are good, but don't get caught up on this. You don't need to know the precise location of stack variables in your program.

Comment: Ok so, basically the advice I'm hearing from both of you, is that unless I aspire to get deeply into building compilers, this is not a curiosity worth pursuing any further. Kinda just chalk up compiler memory allocation to something that is somewhat unpredictable and rarely useful to know about in practice. Correct?

Comment: Thank you both for your insights, I definitely still managed to gain some elucidation on what was going on here. And, perhaps more importantly, when to give up on those darn rabbit holes. Cheers.

Comment: @jvanstry it's useful to have a rough idea of what your compiler does, as it will help you when debugging strange crashes